# Do I need a 24V or 120-240V thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

My Honeywell thermostat just broke. I want to get a new one and install it myself but I don't know whether to get a 24V model or a 120-240v model. There is no indication of this on the one I have. How do I tell?

Comment: I'd poke about with a suitably rated multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

How thick are the wires connected to the thermostat?

24V wiring will be small gauge, usually 22-18 AWG.  It's commonly used for forced air, hot water, and similar systems.

120/240V thermostats will typically use 14-10 AWG, and are commonly used for electric baseboard heaters.

Comment: Also if you have baseboard electric heat it will be 120/240v and if you have a forced warm air system it will be 24v.

Comment: @Mnc123 That's what I said.